# Calculus on Postgres jsonb array of objects

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a Postgres table that has a column of type `jsonb` and that looks like:

```
id   | array_obj
---    ---
id_0 | [ {"Key": "k1", "Value": v1 }, {"Key": "k2", "Value": v2 }, ... ]
```

My goal is to compute something like "value associated to key k1 + value associated to key k3" for instance. I managed to do this by expanding the array `jsonb_to_recordset` and then using a group-by to sum what I needed but this is not very satisfying as I feel like there should be no need for this expansion / aggregation pattern (after all I just want to compute something "row-wise"). Currently the query looks like:

```sql
SELECT
  id,
  sum(val) filter (where k in ('k1', 'k3')) as result,
  sum(case when k in ('k1', 'k2') then 1 else 0 end) as countkeys
FROM 
  my_table, jsonb_to_recordset(array_obj) as expanded(k text, val int)
GROUP BY
  id
```

(`countkeys` is here to address cases when there is 'k1' but no 'k2', hence the sum is not really what's expected, so I then chekc that countkeys equals the number of keys I sum on).

The execution plan is the following (with LIMIT 50):

```sql
Limit  (cost=0.56..256.99 rows=50 width=104) (actual time=0.217..4.965 rows=50 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=166
  ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=0.56..17512338.31 rows=3414645 width=104) (actual time=0.216..4.959 rows=50 loops=1)
        Group Key: my_table.id
        Buffers: shared hit=166
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.56..11485489.89 rows=341464500 width=72) (actual time=0.104..3.396 rows=5301 loops=1)
              Buffers: shared hit=166
              ->  Index Scan using xxx on my_table (cost=0.56..4656199.88 rows=3414645 width=498) (actual time=0.011..0.159 rows=51 loops=1)
                    Filter: (col = 0)
                    Rows Removed by Filter: 64
                    Buffers: shared hit=119
              ->  Function Scan on jsonb_to_recordset expanded  (cost=0.00..1.00 rows=100 width=40) (actual time=0.042..0.047 rows=104 loops=51)
                    Buffers: shared hit=47
Planning:
  Buffers: shared hit=198
Planning Time: 0.552 ms
Execution Time: 5.099 ms
```

So basically I'm just trying to build some kind of "operator" that I could use for "find the value associated to key k" with the kind of data I have. I've tried with the operators listed in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html) but haven't figured it out yet...

Note that this is a first step, my end goal is to compute several aggregates (say `result_1 = value(key_1) + value(key_3)`, `result_2 = value(key_7) + value(key_124)`, etc.) so I'm looking for a solution that does not compute results independantly.

---

In response to the comment of @SelVazi, here is a typical line:

> id | [{"Key":"af_m1","Value":9772},{"Key":"af_m2","Value":7413},{"Key":"af_m3","Value":2359}]

And say I'd like to compute `af_m1 + af_m3 = 9772 + 2359 = 12131`. Note that some line may not have any object with key `af_m1` or `af_m3` in that case we should skip the line (but that's OK I think I can handle it in a second time when I know how to compute what I want first).

Comment: Can you share some input data and the expected output

Comment: I don't think this will address your problem, but it seems unnecessary to have the `{"Key": "k1", "Value": v1 }` when JSON will let you just use `{"k1" : v1}`

Comment: Yes I know but we don't really have hand on this part unfortunately... It was designed this way because there might be other fields than key / value that I don't need in this computation

Comment: Your example query just returns a bunch of NULLs when operating on your example data.

Comment: Please show the entire execution plan including actual timings, not just one context-free snippet.

Comment: @jjanes as currently designed it returns null when there's no element that can be sum. It's ok for me - though it could be tedious when only some keys exist and not the other but that I'll handle in a second time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can save some time, about 30%, by doing the summation in a subquery.  That way it doesn't need to be broken apart, mingled, and then resegregated with a GROUP BY.  The original query uses parallel query which my variant cannot do, so the original is even using more CPU  while it is underperforming.

```
explain (analyze, buffers)
SELECT
  id, 
  (select sum("Value") filter (where "Key" in ('k1', 'k3')) as result from 
     jsonb_to_recordset(array_obj) as expanded("Key" text, "Value" double precision)
  ) as result
from my_table;
```

It would be much faster yet though to just store the data in a sensible format, either up-front or in a materialized view or just a transformed copy.

Comment: It looks promising, I actually have several computations to do so I don't want one subquery for each but I think I can manage something with: 
```sql
SELECT
  id,
  (
    SELECT 
        ARRAY[
            sum("Value") filter (where "Key" in ('k1', 'k3')),
            sum(case when "Key" in ('k1', 'k3') then 1 else 0 end),
            sum("Value") filter (where "Key" in ('kx', 'ky')),
            ...
        ]
    FROM jsonb_to_recordset(array_obj) as expanded("Key" text, "Value" bigint)
  ) as result
FROM my_table
```